How to configure/install the JDBC SQLServerDriver for Spark 3.5 on AWS EMR?
I'm developing a PySpark ETL pipeline application for eventual deployment on AWS EMR. The data is pulled in and out of a Microsoft SQL Server database. When I run the code locally I use a local master and all is well. But when I deploy it on an EMR cluster I get this error when the step runs:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

I thought I'd solved this issue already by specifying the driver's JAR in the SparkSession creation step, like so:
def get_spark_session(
    run_local: bool = False,
    app_name: str = "ETL Pipeline",
    worker_threads: int = 8,
    jars_packages: str = "com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:12.6.1.jre11",
) -> SparkSession:
    """
    Helper function to get a SparkSession object.

    :param run_local: Whether to run the SparkSession locally (typically only for debugging). Defaults to False.
    :param app_name: Name of the Spark application. Defaults to "WCV".
    :param worker_threads: Number of worker threads. Defaults to 8.
    :param jars_packages: Comma-separated list of Maven coordinates for the jars to include on the driver and executor
    :return: the SparkSession object
    """

    # build the SparkSession
    builder = SparkSession.builder.appName(app_name)
    if run_local:
        # set up a local SparkSession builder with the specified number of worker threads
        builder = builder.master(f"local[{worker_threads}]")
        logger.info("Running Spark locally")

    else:
        logger.info("Running Spark on a cluster")

    # configure the SparkSession
    builder = (
        builder.config("spark.jars.packages", jars_packages)
    )

    return builder.getOrCreate()

I'm using EMR version 7.0.0 which includes Spark 3.5.0. From what I can see the latest version of the driver is 12.6.1 and this appears to work fine on my local machine. I can't find any confirmation that this is the correct version to use on EMR 7 though -- where can I find a version compatibility chart?
According to this documentation, the 12.6 release supports Java 17 which is the default version provided in EMR 7.0.0. To wit:

Version 12.6 is the latest general availability (GA) version. It supports Java 8, 11, 17, and 21.

Also, there's this:

The JAR file with jre8 supports Java 8 and the JAR file with jre11 supports Java 11 and up.


I have worked around this issue by downloading the JAR and placing the file on S3. I then added the S3 URI to my spark-submit command for the step using the --jars argument.
